# I have i 10 hyundai 2012 model, paint matalic gray. Suspected cat scratch on engine hood

Tags: engine, hood

![engine hood
Engine hood has scatches as shown in pic.
I suspecy cat scratch, i need your commet on this as per pattern of scatcj[image]

Comment: Don't think that pattern of scratches is due to a cat, since they seem to go in many directions... That looks more like a paint defect with a "crazy paving" effect.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There's a number of these scratches that run parallel for some distance, and around bends, so this isn't the work of a cat. I'd guess that someone has tried to wipe the surface with a rag or sponge with some specks of abrasive material embedded.

Comment: I'm going to disagree here.  That is exactly what cat scratches look like. The curved surface causes them to slide in a slightly circular manner and they leave these types of scratches.  Yes, I've seen this happen personally.

Comment: Cat scratches are generally 4 across, since they usually have all the claws out, or none, and they'll tend to spread as the weight on each paw changes (one of my cars has a few of these), but the noticeable thing about the two I marked out is that they cross one another at the right side. If it's a pirouetting cat, I'd like to see the video....

Comment: It doesn't happen all at once but rather this is the result of the cat getting up on this car time and again.  They slip a bit on the slick surface and you get claw marks.

Answer (score 1):

I will have to agree with the other answer and say that I don't think this was done by a cat.  It's hard to tell exactly what did it, but there's a few reasons I don't believe it's a cat.

1. The scratches are too long and parallel as @Phil G pointed out. Cat's generally don't scratch things in this way and their claws are not perfectly parallel.
2. A cat wouldn't really have a reason to scratch your car.  The metal/paint would more than likely irritate their claws.  Why use a car when there are (I'm assuming) many trees that would work better as a "scratching post" for them?
3. The location of the scratches on the car further points to the fact that it wouldn't be something a cat would be interested in.  What exactly would they be clawing at at that location on your car?  If it was on the sides where it could have been claw marks from climbing up, it makes more sense.

Overall, I would say it's unlikely that this was done by a cat. Only you would have a good idea at who the next suspect would be so I'll leave that up to you

Answer (score 1):

Given the position of the scratches on the bonnet, I would suggest that they are likely caused by someone (human) sitting on it. As Phil G says, the pairs of parallel scratches are too far apart to be cat claws (which would be four closely spaced lines, around 4-5mm apart).